# Finding relative extremes by inspecting a function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I have been given a really obfuscated two-variable function

$f(x, y) = [(x-1)^2 + y^2 - 1][(x+1)^2 + y^2 - 1]$

and I am asked to find the critical points of $f(x, y)$. This is a Calculus exercise from a test. In this context I am really sort on time and I must use every single trick I can think of to save time, otherwise it is not expected that I even get to answer all of the questions. That is to say that even though I could certainly expand the function and then derive it, or derive it as is and then expand it to find the $(x, y)$ pairs that are critical points, that is not, in all likelihood, the "smartest" route.

I have tried to reason about $x$ and $y$ separately, because of the look of the factorization. That reasoning made me conclude that for any given $x$, the function is minimized for $y=0$. That left me wondering if there is a pair $(x, 0)$ for which $f(x, 0)$ attains its minimum, and if I could, in any way, conclude that $f$ has no saddle points (because it obviously has no maximum).

Basically what I am trying to understand is what are the quirks of this function that hint you to reason in such a way that you arrive to the right conclusions, without factoring it out?

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying out a bit:

$$f(x, y) = [(x-1)^2 + y^2 - 1][(x+1)^2 + y^2 - 1] \\= (x^2-1)^2 + (y^2-1)^2 + \left[(x-1)^2 + (x+1)^2\right](y^2-1)$$

Then taking the partial with respect to $x$ gives:

$$f_x(x,y) = 4x(x^2-1) + 4x(y^2-1),$$

And with respect to $y$:

$$f_y(x,y) = 4y(x^2 + 1) + 4y(y^2-1).$$

Seems tenable.  Can you take it from here?